# JQueryUI selectmenu - Como cargar opciones con append

Tags: javascript, html

ojala me puedan ayudar con esto: Estaba usando select option para desplegar un listado de opciones sin problemas, pero por un tema de funcionalidad decidí cambiarlo por un ui selectmenu, sin embargo no me carga nada en el select con el mismo procedimiento que funcionaba con el simple select option

mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
for(x=0; x<cont; x++) {
  $('#proy-select').append('<option value="' + resp['Proyectos'][x]['desc'] + '">' + resp['Proyectos'][x]['id'] + '</option>');
}
```

Lo remplace por este, pero aun así no se carga nada en el select:

```
var options = [];

for(x=0; x<cont; x++) {
  options.push('<option value="' + resp['Proyectos'][x]['desc'] + '">' + resp['Proyectos'][x]['id'] + '</option>');
}

$('#proy-select').append(options.join("")).selectmenu();
$('#proy-select').selectmenu('enable');
```

Se agradece cualquier ayuda

Comment: podrías poner un ejemplo de tu array de datos? De este modo la respuesta obtenida será mas precisa.

Comment: Hola Fran, el array de datos viene en realidad de un tabla sql, pero no hay ningún problema ahí, ya que con un option select simple de HTML se muestran todos los datos sin problema (códigos y descripciones simplemente)

Answer (score -1):

Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo de como puedes realizar la carga de las opciones en el *Select*. Yo lo hice con un for each, pero tranquilamente lo puedes hacer con un for. Espero que te sirva, Saludos!

```js
let proyecto = [
  {'id': 1, 'desc': "item 1"},
  {'id': 2, 'desc': "item 2"},
  {'id': 3, 'desc': "item 3"},
  {'id': 4, 'desc': "item 4"}
];


$(function() {
    fillSelect();
    $( "#mySelect" ).selectmenu({
    select: function( event, ui ) {
     console.log(this.value);
   }
   });
});

function fillSelect()
{
  let select = $("#mySelect");
  $.each(proyecto, function( index, value ) {
    let id= proyecto[index].id;
    let desc= proyecto[index].desc;
    
    $("#mySelect").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+desc+"</option>");
   
  });
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>




<select id="mySelect">
<option disabled selected>Seleccionar...</option>
</select>
```

**Editado**: Adaptado para  jQuery UI Selectmenu

Solo debes agregar el siguiento codigo a la carga de la pagina.

```
$( "#mySelect" ).selectmenu({
    select: function( event, ui ) {
     console.log(this.value);
   }
   });
```

Comment: Fran, muchas gracias por la ayuda, el codigo funciona correctamente para un option select HTML, pero el problema que tengo es con jquery ui menuselect, para el cual no funciona el mismo procedimiento

Comment: @MarioZanetta Listo,  ya esta editado el código con los cambios que deberías hacer.

Comment: Fran, te agradezco mucho, probé tu código y funciona correctamente tal cual lo pones en tu ejemplo. El único problema que me va quedando ahora es que si coloco el select dentro de un popup (necesito mostrralo ahí) viene vacío (esto también me funcionaba correctamente con select option de HTML). Es raro porque si lo saco del popup funcionan bien y dentro no. Sabes si se requiere algún definición adicional ?

Comment: Ya encontré por ahí la solución, hay que agregar estas 2 lineas CSS :                                                                
 .ui-front{z-index:0 !important; } 
.ui-selectmenu-open {z-index:9999 !important;}